# creating Google Drive Picker append into iFrame to my Custom Div use toUri() show Error : 403 you do not have access to this page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I am working on Google Drive Picker I have created a google Drive Picker By using [google Sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample).

but I need to add a google picker inside my custom Div/Module. So I used google Api `.toUri()` that generates src  and append these src to iFrame and appends that iframe inside my custom  Div. i am able to append the Picker to my custom Div
then it shows me this error
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCQKB.png)

```
403. That’s an error.
We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Picker API Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Picker API API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
<div id="pickerDiv"  class="picker-dialog" style="height: 500px; width:800px; border: 1px solid red; position: relative; top: 50%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
  const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';

   const CLIENT_ID = '###########';
   const API_KEY = '########';
   const APP_ID = '######';

  let tokenClient;
  let accessToken = null;
  let pickerInited = false;
  let gisInited = false;


  document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
 
 
  function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('picker', intializePicker);
  }

 
  function intializePicker() {
    pickerInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
  }


  function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
  }

 
  function maybeEnableButtons() {
    if (pickerInited && gisInited) {
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
  }

  
  function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (response) => {
      if (response.error !== undefined) {
        throw (response);
      }
      accessToken = response.access_token;
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
      await createPicker();
    };

    if (accessToken === null) {
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
    } else {
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
    }
  }

 



  function createPicker() {

    
    const view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
    view.setMimeTypes("application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif,image/svg+xml,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/vnd.google-apps.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,video/x-flv,video/mp4,video/quicktime,video/mpeg,video/x-matroska,video/x-ms-asf,video/x-ms-wmv,video/avi,audio/mpeg,audio/wav,audio/ac3,audio/aac,audio/ogg,audio/oga,audio/x-m4a,application/zip")

    const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .setDeveloperKey(API_KEY)
        .setAppId(APP_ID)
        .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
        .addView(view)
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .toUri()

        const myDiv = document.getElementById('pickerDiv');
        const iframe  = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute("src", picker);
        iframe.style.width = "100%";
        iframe.style.height = "100%";
        myDiv.appendChild(iframe)

  }

 
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    
    if (data.action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>

<style>
  .picker-dialog{
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

[console.log(picker)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDhvf.png)

Comment: Can you check what `toUri()` returns? Does not seem like the classic URL. `console.log(picker)`

Comment: PickerBuilder.toUri() Returns the URI generated by this builder.  [API link](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/reference#picker-builder)  [console.log(picker)](https://i.imgur.com/e0rTX8u.png) 
 @Emel

Comment: Maybe this is an issue, you can try opening a new issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).